# how do you enable image loading and disabling it using javascript

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this javascript function. I would like to show image loading while the div is loading. And set the loadking image to null if the div is loaded or there was a an error:

As is, the loading image keeps showing on the page, any ideas what am missing here?

```
$(document).ready(function(){

  $("#submitbutton").on("click", function(){
    //disable the button to prevent multiple clicks
    $("#submitbutton").attr("disabled", "disabled");
    $('#loading').html('<img src="img/loading.gif"> loading...');

    var vcenter = $("#v_name").val();

    vcenter = "'"+vcenter+"'";


    var req = ocpu.rpc("output1", {
      vcenter : vcenter

    }, function(output){

      var data=output;

      });

      req.fail(function(){
        alert("Server error: " + req.responseText);
        $('#loading').html();
      });

      //after request complete, re-enable the button 
      req.always(function(){
        $("#submitbutton").removeAttr("disabled");
         $('#loading').html();
      });

    });
  });
```

html code:

```
<button id="submitbutton" type="button">Submit</button>
  <div id="loading"></div>

  <div id="output"> </div>
```

Answer (score 3):

You need to empty it.

```
$('#loading').html('');
```

That is the fix to your current question. However what I would recommend is something like this:

```
    $(document).ajaxStart(function () {
        $('#loading').css('display', 'block');
    }).ajaxStop(function () {
        $('#loading').css('display', 'none');
    });
```

And the `#loading` div to contain the image from `HTML` already.

Comment: More specifically using `.html()` will return the HTML of the element, not reset it.